# External js script messes up pagespeed

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have an external script that loads `ads` on one of my pages.

Without it I get 90+ score in `pagespeed`. With it I get down to 40.
As the script fills a `div` at the bottom of the page, I tried loading the script after the page is fully loaded. The code below is added in footer:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var tag = document.createElement("script");
   tag.src = "externalscript.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
}
```

But although it runs after page load, it still affects the pagespeed score.
Is there another way to call the script after google evaluates the speed of my page?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `tag.defer = 'defer';` (Place it before `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);`) - [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Tried this, no change. Pagespeed picks the script and i get the following issues that decrease the score: DiagnosticsMore information about the performance of your application. These numbers don't directly affect the Performance score.
Minimize main-thread work 16.4 s
Ensure text remains visible during webfont load
Reduce the impact of third-party code Third-party code blocked the main thread for 3,300 ms

Comment: I had a similar issue. Eventually I decided to use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) that delays the loading of the problematic script for 2 seconds

Comment: Adding a 2sec delay after page load seems to solve this. Thank you!